# Extjs EditorGrid Cell calculation dependency

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs2

Im working on writing a calculation functionality to add dependencies on one or more cells with different formula's (dynamically supplied formula's) on edit of a cell's value.

**Eg: if there are 4 cells a,b,c,d with formula's
a=(editable), b=(a+d), c=(50), d=(a*c/100)**

where "c" is constant. "b" and "d" are dependent on edit of "a".
Like wise i can supply any number of dependencies on "a" like more constants and cells with formula.

I wrote a temporary work around to evaluate some fixed cells with formulas but is there any way to handle dynamically supplied formulas? And can that be a two way sync?

Please Suggest. Thanks

Comment: do you mean cells of a grid with a renderer function?

Comment: having numberfield cell type